# Cloud SQL only working locally

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

So I've been trying to get Cloud SQL working with an app engine backend. I'm using Google Endpoints to send back JSON. It works just fine running locally on my machine, I can hit the service, the resource can hit the database and return results back. However once deployed to GAE, it no longer returns back data. I am using the API explorer tool and I can see the resource getting hit and the it entering the DAO phase. However once it starts to build the connection/prepared statement, it just stops and I don't see a stack trace from any errors. My  Cloud SQL instance is a US instance as I know both the SQL instance and the GAE instance must be in the same region. I don't know how to check if my GAE instance is in the US. Any help in debugging or where to start would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you sign up for Cloud SQl and associate it with your application ID?

Comment: Yes I did. I looked up my application ID and put it on the cloud sql instance settings.

Comment: Could you post some code? Does this work outside of Cloud Endpoints?